# Multiline subscripts in summation notation

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\[
\prod_{k=0,\ k\neq i}^{n}
\frac{x-c_{k}}{c_{i}-c_{k}}
\]
\end{document}
```

I would like to make the `k \neq i`,
which is next to `k=0`, parallel to `k = 0`.
I tried `\\`, `\limits`, and `\begin{align*} ... \end{align*}`, but somehow I did not get the desired result out of the actions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `\substack`, with which you can make a multiline subscript or superscript. <s>Note that you need to load `amsmath` package to use the command.</s>

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\[
\prod_{\substack{k=0\\ k\neq i}}^{n}
\frac{x-c_{k}}{c_{i}-c_{k}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am using amsart? Is not amsmath a built-in package?

Comment: @Chou I noticed you used `amsart` documentclass. Then, you don't need to write `usepackage{amsart}` in the preamble.

Comment: No problem; thank you for taking time to write.

Comment: You should aim to make the answer code compilable and self-contained. If nothing else, that'll save you from having to address follow-up questions of the type above. In the case of your code, it would suffice to insert the instruction `\documentclass{amsart}` at the start of the code block.

Comment: @Mico Thank you for your advice. I updated the answer.